# Install php7.4-cgi in Debian 10

Tags: php, docker, debian

I`m using docker image php:7.4.3-apache and I need to install php7.4-cgi. Image is running on Debian 10. I was tried many tutorials but without success.

Etc. this tutorial https://kifarunix.com/install-php-7-4-on-debian-10-debian-9/

When I run installation command then I get following error:

```
root@eafa0aac715a:/usr/local/bin# apt install php7.4-cgi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php7.4-cgi is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php7.4-cgi' has no installation candidate
```

I don`t known what I am doing bad.

I was created new clear dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.3-apache

RUN apt-get -y install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates curl
RUN wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install php7.4-cgi
```

Is there somebody who can fix this dockerfile for build?

Comment: [`php7.4 cgi !deb`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php7.4+cgi+!deb)

Comment: If you specifically need the `php-cgi` binary, you can alternatively use the `php:<version>-cli` tags

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly configure the repositories to be able to install php?. In my case I use the following repository to install the PHP packages:

```
https://packages.sury.org/php/
```

***How can you configure it in Debian 10?***

First install the necessary packages

```
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates curl
```

Following this, add the GPG key

```
wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
```

then you create a file with following command inside `sources.list.d` directory so `apt` use this repository when updating

```
sh -c 'echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list'
```

and perform an apt-update

```
apt-get update
```

after this, you only have to install the package you were trying to install

```
apt install php7.4-cgi
```

Comment: Yes, I was installed lsb_release other way. I was edit my questin and add example dockerfile for demonstate my problem